# Change default selection when searching in Dash

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash

When I hit the [Super] key, or hit on the Ubuntu button to open up the Dash, is there a way I can change the default "what to search" option to Appplications, instead of HOME (Computer and online sources).
I know <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will do the trick, but I still want to have all the other options open in case I want to search for a file , and still it is easier to open Dash with a click or the hit of one key, rather than a combination.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04